# Why request headers are returned with the response?

Tags: web-services, rest

I am asking a general question here. Are there any situations that the request headers are returned with the response with 404- not found  if we haven't intentionally do it?

Answer (score 1):

There can't be a universal answer to this question. It is entirely possible (but not probable) that someone has built a web server that returns a copy of the request headers as part of a 404 response.

It would be non-standard -- not in compliance with accepted behavior. But there's nothing actually preventing a web server from doing this.

In general, this does not happen. Every response header is added to the response in a way that might be informed by, but not a copy of, the request headers.

Furthermore, the response headers usually have different names than the request headers. There are some exceptions, like `Cache-Control` and `Connection` -- I'm sure there are others, but the semantics of these headers are different in the context of a response than they are in the context of the request, so merely copying them back to the requestor as a general practice would cause serious problems.

I'm wondering why this is a concern for you? Even if you were transmitting sensitive but unencrypted data in the request header (a Very Bad Thing To Do), it could only return the same (known) data back to the requester.

But in practice, no commercial web servers, to my knowledge, ever do this.